# An error occured during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found GetOldTweets3

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

When I try scraping tweets based on username it shows me
"An error occurred during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Try to open in browser: https://twitter.com/search?q=%20from%3A3mindia%20since%3A2020-04-01%20until%3A2020-04-30&src=typd "

The link given is directing me to website which is not a 404.

---

```
    An error occured during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
    Try to open in browser: https://twitter.com/search?q=%20from%3A3mindia%20since%3A2020-04 01%20until%3A2020-04-30&src=typd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\GetOldTweets3\manager\TweetManager.py", line 343, in getJsonResponse
    response = opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-41ed802d4e96>", line 1, in <module>
    CleanTweets("3mindia", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-30", "3M India")
  File "<ipython-input-2-1fa226d02b36>", line 3, in CleanTweets
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\GetOldTweets3\manager\TweetManager.py", line 65, in getTweets
    json = TweetManager.getJsonResponse(tweetCriteria, refreshCursor, cookieJar, proxy, user_agent, debug=debug)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\GetOldTweets3\manager\TweetManager.py", line 348, in getJsonResponse
    sys.exit()
SystemExit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1151, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Monis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this for details on error:

https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98

twitter may have removed the endpoint the GetOldTweets3  - https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?.

Refer to this post also: [Why getoldtweets3 library provides 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952468/why-getoldtweets3-library-provides-404-error)

Answer (score 0):

One user seemed to have [changed the code from the GOT3 library](https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98#issuecomment-695797629) and managed to workaround the issue. The only problem is that the resulting HTML is unformatted. So someone needs to work on that. Specifically the changes they mentioned are:

```
updated user_agents (updated with the ones used by TWINT);

updated endpoint (/search?)

some updates to the URL structure:

url = "https://twitter.com/search?"

    

url += ("q=%%20%s&src=typd%s"
        "&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&max_position=%s"
        "&reset_error_state=false")

if not tweetCriteria.topTweets:
    url += "&f=live"`
```