# Why getoldtweets3 library provides 404 error?

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm using getoldtweets3 library to scrape corona outbreak information. I get this error -

```
error : C:\Users\Vilius\anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Vilius/PycharmProjects/Sentiment-Analysis2/twitter_analysis.py
An error occured during an HTTP request: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Try to open in browser: https://twitter.com/search?q=CoronaOutbreak%20since%3A2020-01-01%20until%3A2020-04-01&src=typd

Even though link is working, what might be the problem?  `https://github.com/attreyabhatt/Sentiment-Analysis` <- I'm using this code

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue that's affecting others as well...

https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98

It seems as if twitter has removed the endpoint the GetOldTweets3 uses (https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?).

Probably going to have to wait for a solution or find some other method of scraping tweets unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this question now:

if you sign up for the "academic" account on the Twitter developer platform, you have access to two different endpoints. One is for recent tweets, one is for "all" tweets and permits the collection of old tweets.

To find out more, read the documentation for the [Twitter API for Academic Research](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api/academic-research).